# How to format a table extracted from salesforce into python?

Tags: python, pandas, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I was able to extract some fields from salesforce using python.

I used the following code block :

```
!pip install simple_salesforce 

from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd

sf = Salesforce(
username='', 
password='', 
security_token='')

sf_data = sf.query_all("SELECT Brand_Name__c,Name FROM AuthorisedProduct__c")

sf_df = pd.DataFrame(sf_data)

sf_df.head()
```

This process puts all items in one 'record' field.

| records | total size |
| --- | --- |
| OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'AuthorisedProduct__c'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/AuthorisedProduct__c/a020o00000xC1fmAAC')])), ('Brand_Name__c', 'ABB'), ('Name', 'UNO-DM-1.2-TL-PLUS-B')]) | 14000 |
| OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'AuthorisedProduct__c'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/AuthorisedProduct__c/a020o00000xC1fnAAC')])), ('Brand_Name__c', 'ABB'), ('Name', 'UNO-DM-1.2-TL-PLUS-SB')]) | 14000 |
| OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'AuthorisedProduct__c'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/AuthorisedProduct__c/a020o00000xC1foAAC')])), ('Brand_Name__c', 'ABB'), ('Name', 'UNO-DM-2.0-TL-PLUS-B')]) | 14000 |

Please note there are 14000 values under records.
I wanted to have only two fields in a simple dataframe. A Table with 'Brand_Name__c' and 'Name' fields.

| Brand_Name__C | Name |
| --- | --- |
| ABB | UNO-DM-2.0-TL-PLUS-B |
| ABB | UNO-DM-1.2-TL-PLUS-SB |

and we will have a matrix of 14000 by 2.

Please advise how to achieve that?

> And also, How to reverse that process?

Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be aware of the actual shape of the JSON response sent by Salesforce, which includes a top-level `"records"` key under which all of your data is contained. Additionally, each record entry contains an `"attributes"` key, besides the data for the fields you actually requested. You cannot change the shape of the JSON response.

There is an example provided in the [`simple_salesforce` documentation](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/tree/dfdb70517a0fe96c06450ccbed8fd41dfd2f1edf) showing how to digest this API response for Pandas:

> Generate Pandas Dataframe from SFDC API Query (ex.query,query_all)

```
import pandas as pd

sf.query("SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact")

df = pd.DataFrame(data['records']).drop(['attributes'],axis=1)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Such a simple solution but yet so effective.

Comment: Please create separate posts for new questions - thanks!

Comment: Thank you David. Created a separate post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68539164/16198455

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the `OrderedDict` object in the `records` column:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'records':[
        OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'AuthorisedProduct__c'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/AuthorisedProduct__c/a020o00000xC1fmAAC')])), ('Brand_Name__c', 'ABB'), ('Name', 'UNO-DM-1.2-TL-PLUS-B')]),
        OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'AuthorisedProduct__c'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/AuthorisedProduct__c/a020o00000xC1fnAAC')])), ('Brand_Name__c', 'ABB'), ('Name', 'UNO-DM-1.2-TL-PLUS-SB')]),
        OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'AuthorisedProduct__c'), ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/AuthorisedProduct__c/a020o00000xC1foAAC')])), ('Brand_Name__c', 'ABB'), ('Name', 'UNO-DM-2.0-TL-PLUS-B')])
    ],
    'total size': [14000]*3
})

df['Brand_Name__c'] = df['records'].apply(lambda x: x['Brand_Name__c'])
df['Name'] = df['records'].apply(lambda x: x['Name'])
```

Result:

```
>>> df
                                             records  total size Brand_Name__c                   Name
0  {'attributes': {'type': 'AuthorisedProduct__c'...       14000           ABB   UNO-DM-1.2-TL-PLUS-B
1  {'attributes': {'type': 'AuthorisedProduct__c'...       14000           ABB  UNO-DM-1.2-TL-PLUS-SB
2  {'attributes': {'type': 'AuthorisedProduct__c'...       14000           ABB   UNO-DM-2.0-TL-PLUS-B
```

Comment: Hi Derek, Thank you. I have 14000 values in records column. That size keeps changing every week, and hence the objective to retrieve the data from Salesforce.  It is not possible to fit in 14000 entries in df that way. I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi Dr. Islam, thanks for your comment. I understand that your goal is to properly format the `records` column using the `simple_salesforce` package, and that my solution is more of a workaround after the fact. I'll see what I can figure out

Comment: Thank you Derek. I will wait to hear from you. I appreciate your kind support. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested to this topic I made a package to solve this once for all. It does recursive un-nesting so you can make multiple-level relationship queries (not just two levels) and get a plain dataframe as ouptut.

`pip install simpler-sf`

```
import simpler_sf
simpler_sf.simple_salesforce()
import simple_salesforce

sf = simple_salesforce.Salesforce(...)

query = 'SELECT Contact.Id, Account.Name, Campaign FROM CampaignMember'

df = sf.smart_query(query)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Contact.FirstName   Account.Name           Campaign
0   Emily                     Amazon   CampaignA_2023Q2
1   Jasmine                   Amazon   CampaignA_2023Q2
2   Míng                   Microsoft   CampaignB_2022Q4
```

Here's the link to the github [repo](https://github.com/benvigano/simpler-sf/)